# Python command to control a local host arduino device

Tags: python, arduino, urllib2, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

My first time posting, but I am really stuck, and need help.

I am currently working on a home automation system where I want to control a remote Arduino device using a router.

That part is all done, and I can connect to links using a browser that can turn on or turn off. I even made an app with it.

Currently I am working on a speech recognition code, that takes a code and then translates in to speech, the speech recognition part is working well with the SpeechRecognition library, once python understands the code, it has to give a command and use the url.

If I try to access urls like http://www.google.com, I think it works, however my URL is "http://192.168.0.227/LED=ON14" and when using this, the program hangs and then timesout, I have already tried several ways to control it, but none of them seem to work.

```
import urllib2

sock = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.0.227/LED=ON14") 
htmlSource = sock.read()                            
sock.close()                                        
print htmlSource
```

this was my latest trial

```
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
>     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
>     response = self._open(req, data)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
>     '_open', req)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
>     result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
>     return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1194, in do_open
>     h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1039, in request
>     self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in _send_request
>     self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1035, in endheaders
>     self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 879, in _send_output
>     self.send(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 841, in send
>     self.connect()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 822, in connect
>     self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
>     sock.connect(sa)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
>     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
```

which ended with that response.

My Arduino code is for ESP8266 is:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "--";
const char* password = "--";

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);digitalWrite(12, LOW);digitalWrite(13, LOW);digitalWrite(15, LOW);  digitalWrite(2,LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 106);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress dns(192, 168, 0, 1);

// Static IP Setup Info Here...
WiFi.config(ip,dns, gateway, subnet); //If you need Internet Access You should Add DNS also... 
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();
    int value = LOW;
// Return the response
 /*client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON14\"\"><button>Turn On 4 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF14\"\"><button>Turn Off 4</button></a><br />");  
    client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON12\"\"><button>Turn On 2 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF12\"\"><button>Turn Off 2</button></a><br />");  
    client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON13\"\"><button>Turn On 3 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF13\"\"><button>Turn Off 3</button></a><br />");  
    client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON15\"\"><button>Turn On 1 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF15\"\"><button>Turn Off 1</button></a><br />");  
  client.println("</html>"); */

  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

  // Match the request


  if (request.indexOf("/ON4") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF4") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }
    if (request.indexOf("/ON3") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF3") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }
    if (request.indexOf("/ON2") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("OFF2") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }
    if (request.indexOf("/ON1") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(15, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF1") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(15, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }



}
```

Comment: Can you post your arduino/esp8266 code as well. It could be that the raspberry don't get a "200 OK" header response.

Comment: Edited the post, I am not aware of HTML coding much.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'urllib2' maybe is looking for the end html bracket `</html>`
Try putting a `client.println("</html>");` in between `client.print("Led pin is now: ");` and `delay(1);`
And also if you would like it to print te state of the led to the client, you should move your LED controle statements above the code where your are sending to the client and pass in the `value`.

So your code would look like this.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "--";
const char* password = "--";

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(14, LOW);digitalWrite(12, LOW);digitalWrite(13, LOW);digitalWrite(15, LOW);  digitalWrite(2,LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 106);
  IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
  IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
  IPAddress dns(192, 168, 0, 1);

  // Static IP Setup Info Here...
  WiFi.config(ip,dns, gateway, subnet); //If you need Internet Access You should Add DNS also... 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request
  int value = LOW;    

  if (request.indexOf("/ON4") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(14, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF4") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(14, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }
    if (request.indexOf("/ON3") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF3") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }
    if (request.indexOf("/ON2") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF2") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }
    if (request.indexOf("/ON1") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(15, LOW);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF1") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(15, HIGH);
    value = LOW;
  }


  // Return the response
  /*client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON14\"\"><button>Turn On 4 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF14\"\"><button>Turn Off 4</button></a><br />");  
    client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON12\"\"><button>Turn On 2 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF12\"\"><button>Turn Off 2</button></a><br />");  
    client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON13\"\"><button>Turn On 3 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF13\"\"><button>Turn Off 3</button></a><br />");  
    client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON15\"\"><button>Turn On 1 </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF15\"\"><button>Turn Off 1</button></a><br />");  
  client.println("</html>"); */

  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");
  client.println(value);                  // Parse in the value
  client.println("</html>");              // Add this

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

}
```

Unfortunetly I don't have the ability to test this right now so I hop it works. Else leve a comment.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your time.

For some reason, i think the page settings are fine, i tried as you said, but it still did not work.

The issue I think is the access of my raspberry pi to local network pages such as the on I am using, for instance if I use my browser PC, to open the link it works. But from the chromium browser in my raspberry pi, it doesnt work and stops responding, I still do not know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What are the IP address of the Pi? Is it in the same scope as the ESP? Try to open the page in chrome and right-click and choose investigate, select Console pane and see if there are any errors. Sometime modern browsers are more forgiven than simpler ones.